# Make a temporary data holder in java .spring . hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I work on a project that makes service for mobile apps and also 
I should make a project that monitor the Mobile Project.
I want to make some reports that show how many messages  come in this moment
and some other reports like that.

but I don’t want to get queries in monitoring project directly from DB.
I want to make a temporary data holder in memory and save the last 10 minutes 
data on it (like a variable or a list)
but I don’t know technically how?
I use Spring and Hibernate in my project.

Answer (score 2):

First of all we assume that our program tries to refresh the reports of an entity called *SampleEntity* every 10 minutes. This is just a simple POJO.

```
public class SampleEntity
{
    // your fields and their getters and setters
}
```

Next we have a class, I call it *SampleEntityDA*, which queries the records we need for our reports from db. **As you use hibernate you can simply return the result as java.util.List** (I think this is one your main problems).

```
public class SampleEntityDA
{
    public List<SampleEntity> queryFromDB()
    {
         // fetch records you need for your reports here
         Session session = ...
         return session.createQuery("from sampleEntity").list();
    }
}
```

And at last...

*query from db every 10 minutes*...

To query from db every 10 minutes, you can simply use java.util.Timer class.

```
public class ReportTimer extends Observable
{
    private Timer timer;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Your program starts from here
        new ReportTimer().start();
    }

    private void start()
    {
        // schedule method of Timer class can execute a task repeatedly.
        // This method accepts a TimerTask interface instance as its first parameter.I implement
        // it as an anonymous class. TimerTask interface has a run method. Code in this method will execute repeatedly.
        // Its second parameter is delay before task gets started to execute.
        // And its third parameter is the interval between each execution(10min in your case)
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(
                new TimerTask()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        notifyObservers(
                            new SampleEntityDA().queryFromDB() // 10 minutes passed from the last query, now its time to query from db again...
                       );
                    }
                }, 100, 600000); // 600000ms = 10min
    }

    public void finish()
    {
        // call me whenever you get tired of refreshing reports
        timer.cancel();
    }
}
```

At last you need to update the data holder of your reports every 10min.

You can do this simply by *Observer Pattern*. As you know in java this is done by Observer class and Observable interface.
So 1) ReportTimer needs to extend Observer class and 2) in TimerTask we need to notify the listeners; this is done by notifyObservers method.

Our last class has duty of refreshing reports. I call it ReportGenerator. This class refreshes the reports whenever you like. It also has a java.util.List field that has the most recent data of db. ReportGenerator updates this field whenever its Observer - I mean ReportTimer - notifies it.

```
public class ReportGenerator implements Observer
{

List<SampleEntity> list = new ArrayList<SampleEntity>();

@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg)
{
    // This method will automatically!?! executed whenever its observer notifies him.
    // The arg parameter consists the new records. you just need to put it in the list field.
    List<SampleEntity> list = (List<SampleEntity>) arg;
}

public void refreshReport()
{
    // you can easily refresh a report with data in list field
}

public void refreshAnotherReport()
{
    // you can easily refresh a report with data in list field
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use map, hashMap, or ConcurrentHashMap.
make a crone job that update Map after ten min.

Here is a  link for  [map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), [ConcurrentHashMAP](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)